# Is there any way to get upload file percentage using Flurl library?

Tags: c#, file-upload, percentage, flurl

I am uploading some file to using web API and I am using **Flurl** for that but I am not getting any way to get upload **percentage** or any information that can help me to get upload file percentage.

Answer (score 1):

Flurl doesn't provide direct support for this, but with knowledge of [how to do it with HttpClient](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+httpclient+upload+progress+site:stackoverflow.com), you should be able to adapt it to Flurl. The basic steps would be:

1. Create a class that inherits from `HttpContent` and contains the bits necessary to track progress. One example is described in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35340010/62600).
2. Use Flurl's `PostAsync` method (which takes an `HttpContent` object) to send it.